# re.search in python, return a list of integers separated by comma

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a list of strings as follows:

```
my_list = ['array("i", [12694499, 12855016, 123457])',
'array("i", [12694499, 12865016, 123457])',
'array("i", [12694499, 12855016])',
'array("i", [12699749, 12877477])',
'array("i", [12828285, 12868277])',
'array("i", [-1])',
'array("i", [-1])',
'array("i", [-1])']
```

I am a newbie using regular expressions in python and I'm trying to use re.search to extract the values in brackets and separated by commas. As follows:

```
[12694499, 12855016, 123457]
[12694499, 12865016, 123457]
[12694499, 12855016]
[12699749, 12877477]
[12828285, 12868277]
[-1]
[-1]
[-1]
```

I have tried this:

```
for value in my_list:
    coords = re.search(r"\[[0-9]+,\s[0-9]+\]", value)
    print(coords)
```

but I get this:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

I know I can use split() to get the numbers, but I'm really interested in understand how RE works in python.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't get that result. I get 2 None, 3 matches, then 3 None. Your regexp only matches when there are exactly 2 numbers in the brackets.

Comment: Your regexp also doesn't match negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually has a match for the 3rd, 4th and 5th item.

But if you want to get all the matches, you can use an optional hyphen `-?` and optionally repeat the part with the comma and the digits `(?:,\s-?[0-9]+)*`

Then first check the result of `re.search` and print the value with `.group()`

```
for value in my_list:
    coords = re.search(r"\[-?[0-9]+(?:,\s-?[0-9]+)*]", value)
    if coords:
        print(coords.group())
```

Output

```
[12694499, 12855016, 123457]
[12694499, 12865016, 123457]
[12694499, 12855016]
[12699749, 12877477]
[12828285, 12868277]
[-1]
[-1]
[-1]
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5z1naP).